# Setting different colors to different textviews within a layout not working

Tags: android, textview

I am currently setting up 3 textviews that go into a LinearLayout(code below). However the last color that is assigned using the setColor method only seems to apply to the first textview and in fact overwrites the color that i had initially set for it.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView view1 = new TextView(this);
    view1.setText("I am view one");
    view1.setTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
    view1.setTextSize(25);
    view1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    TextView view2 = new TextView(this);
    view2.setText("I am view two");
    view1.setTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLUE));
    view2.setTextSize(30);
    view2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    TextView view3 = new TextView(this);
    view3.setText("I am view three");
    view1.setTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.YELLOW));
    view3.setTextSize(50);
    view3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


    LinearLayout myLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    myLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    myLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    myLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    myLinearLayout.addView(view1);
    myLinearLayout.addView(view2);
    myLinearLayout.addView(view3);

    setContentView(myLinearLayout);
```

In this case view1 is yellow and the other views are grey...red and blue aren't being applied to the correct views. As a note i initially had just tried to use setColor and as you can see i was trying to use ColorStateList per the documentation but the same results apply. Anyhow, how would i go about forcing the color i want on the different textviews? I know this should be easy, perhaps i am just missing something here. thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the objects you are setting the colors on - it seems like there's a whole bunch of copy-paste left-overs. Every color assignment is done on `view1`, whereas what you really want is to set the color in the second assignment to `view2`, and in the third to `view3`:

```
TextView view1 = new TextView(this);
view1.setText("I am view one");
view1.setTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
view1.setTextSize(25);
view1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

TextView view2 = new TextView(this);
view2.setText("I am view two");
view2.setTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLUE)); // <-- view2
view2.setTextSize(30); 
view2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

TextView view3 = new TextView(this);
view3.setText("I am view three");
view3.setTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.YELLOW)); // <-- view3
view3.setTextSize(50);
view3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

By the way, simple calling `.setColor(Color.RED)` (or a different color) on the views should suffice.

Comment: oh my word. talk about EPIC FAIL. i guess thats what happens when you've been coding for 8 hours. thanks for noticing. i probably would have gotten it sooner or later. that all fixed it. hopefully next time i'll ask a question that isn't so obvious :)

Comment: We've all been there, trust me. A fresh pair of eyes always helps. Happy coding :)